# Random color for uiview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

In my xcode i have a uiview which is dynamic

```
UIView *gaping=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 172, 39)];
    gaping.backgroundColor= [UIColor redColor];
```

I need the background color to be dynamically change.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIView *gaping=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 172, 39)];
    gaping.backgroundColor= [UIColor redColor];


    UITableViewCell *TableCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *RRTYRT = [DATAARRAY objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *LabelOne = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 0, 100, 30)];
    LabelOne.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    LabelOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    LabelOne.text = [RRTYRT objectForKey:@"themename"];
    [gaping addSubview:LabelOne];

    [gaping.layer setCornerRadius:5.8f];

    [TableCell.contentView addSubview:gaping];
    return TableCell;

}
```

The below mentioned code is the table view within which i have this view and for each cell of the tableview i need to change the color of this UiView. I know its a bit confusing to understand so please if anyone can help me it would be aooritiable .

Thanks

Comment: **Very very bad naming convention**

Comment: where is the random color, for each cellview it has same `white` color.

Comment: not able to understand

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use like this and make your color what you want:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIView *gaping=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 172, 39)];

    CGFloat redLevel    = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
    CGFloat greenLevel  = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
    CGFloat blueLevel   = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;

    gaping.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: redLevel
                                                green: greenLevel
                                                 blue: blueLevel
                                                alpha: 1.0];


    UITableViewCell *TableCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *RRTYRT = [DATAARRAY objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *LabelOne = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 0, 100, 30)];
    LabelOne.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    LabelOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    LabelOne.text = [RRTYRT objectForKey:@"themename"];
    [gaping addSubview:LabelOne];

    [gaping.layer setCornerRadius:5.8f];

    [TableCell.contentView addSubview:gaping];
    return TableCell;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a random color from [Tapku library](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary)

```
- (UIColor*) randomColor{
    int r = arc4random() % 255;
    int g = arc4random() % 255;
    int b = arc4random() % 255;
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1];
}

And to use it:
LabelOne.backgroundColor = [self randomColor];
```

But you should consider read some articles about developing in objective-c, and the proper uses of `UITableView` with reusing cells

Answer (score 3):

```
UIColor *color;
float randomRed = arc4random() % 255;
float randomGreen = arc4random() % 255;
float randomBlue = arc4random() % 255;

 gaping.backgroundColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:randomRed green:randomGreen blue:randomBlue alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice way to get random background color similar to clear app effect:

```
-(UIColor*)bcgColorForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
    NSUInteger rowCount = [YOURARRAY count] - 1; //it's your array which gives you all rows for data source
    float value = ((float)indexPath.row / (float)rowCount) * 0.5; // You can change this value depends on your needs
    return [UIColor colorWithRed: 1.0 green:value blue: 0.0 alpha:1.0]; // You can make different color dynamic, for example red, it's deepends on your requirements
}
```

And you call it like that:

```
gaping.backgroundColor = [self bcgColorForIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int lowerBound = 1;
int upperBound = 255;
int red = lowerBound + arc4random() % (upperBound - lowerBound);
int green = lowerBound + arc4random() % (upperBound - lowerBound);
int blue = lowerBound + arc4random() % (upperBound - lowerBound);
[gaping setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Any changes to the background color of a cell into cellForRowAtIndexPath are ignored. Instead change cell color in:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [self bcgColorForIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

...using Greg's bcgColorForIndexPath method.

Answer (score -1):

Just instantiate some `UIColor` to  an array of colors:

```
NSMutableArray *myColors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor blackColor], [UIColor pinkColor], [UIColor yellowColor] , nil];
```

And then set your `UIView` backgroundColor as follow:

```
gaping.backgroundColor= [myColors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

if it solves your purpose, let me know.
Feel free ask further.

Comment: not works.. help